# Pi Calculator In Python, is it fully functional?

Tags: python-3.2, pi

I have created (with some help) this pi generator and wondered if it is fully functional and will continue to work without breaking.
it runs in Python3.2

```
a, b = 0, 1
while 1:
    a = a + (4/b)
    b = b + 2

    a = a - (4/b)
    b = b + 2
    print(str(a))
```

Comment: i don't understand your question.

Comment: This code starts to generate PI, will it continue forever or will it stop at any point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put, yes.

Long answer, it will work for all versions of python 3.x